# Initialize numeric value of an object

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

i am trying to do things with a model (written in python and solved with pyomo and guroby) in which i have several costs calculated in this form:

```
cost_i=sum(M.VariableCost[technology,year]*M.V_Activity[technology,year])
```

Where M.V_Activity is a model decision variable and the cost is the sum for each technology and year defined in the model.

The objective function, is the sum of several costs, in this form:

```
economic_cost = cost_i+ cost_j+ cost_x
```

I want to add an other term to the function, this will be called "environmental cost" and will have the same order of magnitude of the "economic cost", because i want the new term to have a weight comparable to the others in the final objective function, that will be written in the form:

```
final_cost = economic_cost+ENVIRONMENTAL_COST
```

I'm trying to establish the order of magnitude of economic_cost trough a cycle,in order to find the exponent that i have to apply at the Environmental_cost in order to make it count, the cycle is in this form:

```
if value(economic_cost) >10:
...do things
else:
...do others
```

The model raise the error:

No value for uninitialized NumericValue object V_Capacity [...]

Where V_Capacity is the term that appears in the cost formulation i have written above (the first one).

I know the problem is in the if value() row ,since when i call the value of the economic_cost, this has not been calculated yet. I would need something that act as a placeholder until a value is defined, but really don't know what to do.

Someone knows how to solve and to let the model run?

Comment: you need to add `:` in you if else statement.

Comment: Thank you, but the : is just a matter of syntax here on stack, in the model is properly written. The core business of this question is how pyomo solve the objective function in my abstract model, the reason for which i'm getting the ValueError

Comment: The "if" is not passed on to the solver for evaluation, only expressions are. Besides Gurobi does not allow general non-linear functions. So this is an error on two fronts.

Comment: Thank you Erwin, so, in order to  have an objective function with the sum of two different parameters, in which you have to bring the smaller parameter at the same scale/magnitude of the highest in order to make it count in the optimization, what do you suggest?

Comment: No. I don't know enough about what "do things" and "do others" are (so I am guessing a bit here -- my mindreading skills are limited), but typically one would use binary variables to handle the different cases. Or a disjunctive programming tool.

Comment: Ok thank you, and sorry for the missing information,but the fact i haven't specified the content of the if cycle is due to the fact the model never enters into it, because it stops at the value(), because for the variable it doesn't have any value. Basically what i need to do is optimize an objective function made of two terms, different in nature, that i want to bring at the same scale in order to make them count equal in the optimization. If for example one term is 10^10 and the other 10^2, the second will be negligible.

Comment: the if cycle is only a way to calculate the exponent, by dividing value over 10 until it's less than 10, and counting how many times the division happened

Comment: In your opinion, is this kind of operation feasible with pyomo? I've read many point of view about this, and lot of peole say is hard since pyomo only generates an expression which is sent to the solver. So you cannot establish the scale/magnitude of an expression :(

Comment: Weights usually have to be constant to make sense.

Comment: Just to try to clarify the relationship between your code and the model as this is a common misunderstanding. The code that you write does not solve the problem. Your code (using pyomo in this case) is setting up a mathematical model in the solver (Gurobi in this case). When your code has built the model, then you call solve() or similar on the solver which then solves the problem model your code created. So your model building code (using pyomo or whatever) CANNOT have access to the values of any of the variables in your model until AFTER it has been solved because they DON'T have a value.